# DeltaImport not happening by default

Tags: sql, sql-server, solr, lucene

I'm having issues with deltaquery where it's doesn't work automatically. Below is the data-config I have

```
        <dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
       driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
       url="jdbc:sqlserver://WTL-sql-1.com;databaseName=eng_metrics"
       user="metrics"
       password="metrics"/>

        <document name="content">
            <entity name="id"
    query="select defect_id,headline,description,modify_date,issue_type,category,product,state FROM defects WHERE state not like 'Duplicate'"
    deltaImportQuery="select defect_id,headline,description,modify_date,issue_type,category,product,state FROM defects WHERE defect_id = '${dataimporter.delta.defect_id}' and state not like 'Duplicate'"
    deltaQuery="select defect_id FROM defects WHERE modify_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">

                <field column="defect_id" name="defect_id" />
                <field column="headline" name="headline" />
                <field column="description" name="description" />
                <field column="modify_date" name="modify_date" />            
                <field column="issue_type" name="issue_type" />
                <field column="category" name="category" />
                <field column="product" name="product" />
                <field column="state" name="state" />
            </entity>
        </document>
    </dataConfig>
```

But what I see that no matter the modify_date changes in the DB, I don't see any update happening unless I try doing a delta import explicitly.

Can someone provide me some thoughts on whether I need to change some config or some query to make that happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, DataImportHandler will not do it automatically. You have to trigger it by call delta import 's url.

You may want something like this:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling

or you can implement similar one by youself.

Comment: I've added a reply to this above.. somehow I'm not able to post it here.. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

But I've this data-config which works fine in some cases

```
    <dataConfig> 
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
       driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
       url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=sustaining_trends"
       user="sa"
       password="metrics"/>

        <document name="content">
            <entity name="id"
    query="select id,createtime,lastmodified,modifiedby,title,keywords,general,symptom,diagnosis,resolution FROM trends"
    deltaImportQuery="select id,createtime,lastmodified,modifiedby,title,keywords,general,symptom,diagnosis,resolution FROM trends WHERE id = ${dataimporter.delta.id}"
    deltaQuery="select id FROM trends WHERE lastmodified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' or createtime > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">

                <field column="id" name="trendid" />
                <field column="lastmodified" name="lastmodified" />
                <field column="modifiedby" name="modifiedby" />
                <field column="title" name="title" />
                <field column="keywords" name="keywords" />
                <field column="general" name="general" />
                <field column="symptom" name="symptom" />
                <field column="diagnosis" name="diagnosis" />
                <field column="resolution" name="resolution" />
            </entity>
        </document>
    </dataConfig>
```

Here if the item is modified immediately that gets updated without any interference but if a new data is created that doesn't get updated until either I do a manual delta import or else some entry gets modified.

How does this work automatically incase of modification and not work automatically for creation?